# Azure AD B2C: Is it possible to do Self Service Password Reset via graph api only

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a use case, where in app we would like to allow users to reset their password if needed using the sspr, however it only seems possible via the web interface (no api methods for these).  My question is, is it possible to facilitate sspr api only in app, or are we stuck with a web interface for now for this functionality?

My question is, is it possible to facilitate sspr api only in app, or are we stuck with a web interface for now for this functionality?

Comment: You could build it yourself in your app updating the user's passwordProfile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http. But then you need to do the email verification etc. yourself of course.

Comment: Also bear in mind that password validation is typically handled by B2C policies and updating the password via Graph API would bypass that, meaning you'd need to ensure your validation logic is also implemented in your app as well as in B2C.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the response.  This was what I thought as well.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#code-sample-how-to-programmatically-manage-user-accounts